# Animating from offscreen with TranslateAnimation causes adjacent view to be clipped

Tags: android

Right now I have a view that I'm just popping onto the screen by changing the view from GONE to VISIBLE, and I instead want to have a TranslateAnimation that shifts the view onto the screen. As soon as the animation starts the view on the right becomes clipped though. I assume this is because the parent view is taking the width of the view on the left and factoring that into the view calculation? Is there any way to not have that happen, so it looks like both views are shifting onto and off of the screen? Setting

```
android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false"
```

didn't seem to help

Comment: Can you show the code? It should work - set the view to visible then start the animation

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem when doing this programmatically. setClipChildren and setClipToPadding have no effect for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false"
on the parent container